# Why does my object keep getting NaN values?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I´ve been messing around with a library called p5.js and I encounter a problem while trying to modify the values of an object. After creating the array and pushing the objects I check for the object and it has many NaN values. This code can be run in editor.p5js.org for free in case you need it. Thanks in advance.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);

  background(0);

  p = [];
  planetnum = 3; //Set one more 
  for (u = 0; u < planetnum; u++) {
    p.push({
      rx: 0,
      ry: 0,
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      ax: 0,
      ay: 0,
      m: 10
    });
  }
  for (u = 0; u < planetnum; u++) {
    p[u].rx = 0;
    p[u].ry = 0;
    p[u].vx = 0;
    p[u].vy = 0;
    p[u].ax = 0;
    p[u].ay = 0;
    p[u].m = 10;
  }

  p[0].ry = 100;
  p[1].rx = 100;
  p[2].rx = -100;
  console.log(p[1]);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  scale(1, -1);
  console.log("Working");
  color(255);
  //Calculate next position
  for (i = 0; i < planetnum; i++) {
    p[i].ax = 0;
    p[i].ay = 0;
    console.log(p[i]);
    for (o = 0; o < planetnum; o++) {
      if (o != i) {
        d = sqrt((p[i].ry - p[o].ry) ^ 2 + (p[i].rx - p[o].rx) ^ 2);
        f = -0.001 / (d * d);
        angle = Math.atan2((p[i].ry - p[o].ry), (p[i].rx - p[o].rx));

        p[i].ax += f * d * Math.cos(angle) / p[i].m;
        p[i].ay += f * d * Math.sin(angle) / p[i].m;
      }
    }
    p[i].vx += p[i].ax;
    p[i].ay += p[i].ay;
    p[i].rx += p[i].vx;
    p[i].ry += p[i].vy;
  }

  //Draw circles
  for (i = 0; i < planetnum; i++) {
    circle(p[i].rx, p[i].ry, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you need the loop that sets the properties like `p[u].rx = 0`? You set all those values when you were pushing the objects.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the formula that's setting `p[i].ax` and `p[i].ay` in the "Calculate next position" code. Check those values.

Comment: I´m setting all properties again cause I thought they were not set (deleted that part and still fails) and yeah the atan2 returns NaN cause it is given Nan. The object values after creating it are half null. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you wrote this code:

```js
d = sqrt((p[i].ry - p[o].ry) ^ 2 + (p[i].rx - p[o].rx) ^ 2);
```

Your intention was to square each of those deltas. However, in JavaScript `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not the exponent operator. This is probably resulting in your taking the square root of -1 which is NaN. This fixes the NaN problem:

```js
d = sqrt((p[i].ry - p[o].ry) ** 2 + (p[i].rx - p[o].rx) ** 2);
```

Note: on certain defunct browsers you might need to use `Math.pow(p[i].ry - p[o].ry, 2)`, also you could consider the p5.js dist function: `dist(p[i].rx, p[i].ry, p[o].rx, p[o].ry)`.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);

  background(0);

  p = [];
  planetnum = 3; //Set one more 
  for (u = 0; u < planetnum; u++) {
    p.push({
      rx: 0,
      ry: 0,
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      ax: 0,
      ay: 0,
      m: 10
    });
  }
  for (u = 0; u < planetnum; u++) {
    p[u].rx = 0;
    p[u].ry = 0;
    p[u].vx = 0;
    p[u].vy = 0;
    p[u].ax = 0;
    p[u].ay = 0;
    p[u].m = 10;
  }

  p[0].ry = 100;
  p[1].rx = 100;
  p[2].rx = -100;
  console.log(p[1]);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  console.log("Debug:");
  for (i = 0; i < planetnum; i++) {
    console.log(p[i]);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  scale(1, -1);
  color(255);
  //Calculate next position
  for (i = 0; i < planetnum; i++) {
    p[i].ax = 0;
    p[i].ay = 0;
    for (o = 0; o < planetnum; o++) {
      if (o != i) {
        d = sqrt((p[i].ry - p[o].ry) ** 2 + (p[i].rx - p[o].rx) ** 2);
        f = -0.001 / (d * d);
        angle = Math.atan2((p[i].ry - p[o].ry), (p[i].rx - p[o].rx));

        p[i].ax += f * d * Math.cos(angle) / p[i].m;
        p[i].ay += f * d * Math.sin(angle) / p[i].m;
      }
    }
    p[i].vx += p[i].ax;
    p[i].ay += p[i].ay;
    p[i].rx += p[i].vx;
    p[i].ry += p[i].vy;
  }

  //Draw circles
  for (i = 0; i < planetnum; i++) {
    circle(p[i].rx, p[i].ry, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```